# Angular - configurable feature module return other modules in forRoot

Tags: angular, module

I have the following scenario.

1. I want to create a configurable feature module (ModuleA) with a static create method **forRoot**
2. ModuleA will use in the imports array another module (ModuleB)
3. ModuleB also has a static create method where you can pass options to ModuleB
4. ModuleA configuration options should have inside the configuration for ModuleB

In code it will look something like so:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ModuleB.forRoot(<the options here we need to take from ModuleA options>)
    ]
})
export class ModuleA {
    forRoot(options): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
            ngModule: ModuleA,
            providers: [
                {provide: SOME_TOKEN, useValue: options}
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

The solutions has to be compatible with AOT.

How can I grab the options passed to ModuleA and use them to configure ModuleB?

Is there a way where i can instead of returning in the **forRoot** an object of type **ModuleWithProviders** I can return an object with multiple modules?

If no what is the recommended way to do this?

Also I'm aware that I can just define ModuleB in the parent but would rather not do that since it means that everyone that uses ModuleA will have to manually add repetitive code of all the configurable modules that ModuleA are using.

Thanks